# Can I rely on `compare_total` to properly compare decimals values, including inf, nan, etc?

Tags: python, comparison, decimal, nan

Using `x == y` fails to achieve my purpose when both `x` and `y` are equal to `Decimal('nan')`.

I believe that instead of `x == y`, I can rely on `not x.compare_total(y)`.

A quick experiment implies that [compare_total](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.compare_total) might indeed work:

```
from decimal import Decimal

values = [
    '0',
    '-1',
    '+1',
    '-inf',
    '+inf',
    'nan'
]

for x in values:
    for y in values:
        dx = Decimal(x)
        dy = Decimal(y)
        print(x == y, not dx.compare_total(dy))
```

Can I indeed rely on this method?

Comment: The problem with `compare_total` is that `Decimal('12.0').compare_total(Decimal('12')) != 0` because it *Compares two operands using their abstract representation rather than their numerical value*

Comment: Your provided code gives same results for `x==y` and `not dx.compare_total(dy)` in all cases.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: Thank you for this important observation. Would you know of a good workaround for this (of course, I could just test `x == y` or (x.isnan() and y.isnan())`, but ideally, Id prefer something "cleaner" and easier to read).

Comment: @matszwecja: Thank you, but that's exactly what I already wrote in my question. I am asking if I can rely on this observation for any values of 'x' and 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out `.normalize()` method of Decimal objects. [Its documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) specifically states: "Used for producing canonical values for attributes of an **equivalence class.**"

```
from decimal import Decimal

print(Decimal('12.0').normalize().compare_total(Decimal('12').normalize())) # 0
print(Decimal('nan').normalize().compare_total(Decimal('nan').normalize())) # 0
print(Decimal('12.0').normalize().compare_total(Decimal('nan').normalize())) # -1
```

Whether it is very clean is arguable, but you could extract it into a function for readability:

```
def compare_normalized(dx, dy):
    return dx.normalize().compare_total(dy.normalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own `Decimal` class inherited from `decimal.Decimal` and override the `__eq__` operator:

```
class Decimal(decimal.Decimal):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Decimal):
            return super().__eq__(other) or (self.isnan() and other.isnan())
        else:
            return False
```

As @matszwecja mentioned in the comment, that breaks the hashing of the `Decimal` which doesn't allow it to be used in sets or dicts' keys. To fix that, you could just redefine `__hash__` method:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return super().__hash__()
```

Comment: This might cause serious unexpected issues. For example, you cannot add such decimal to a set, while set with standard Decimal works fine.

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks for noting that. I've updated the answer. Do you think this still can cause any other problems?

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that comparison to other types will not work if `super().__eq__(other)` evaluates to false and the other type has no `isnan` method (e.g. `Decimal("1") == 0`